# Armature on character missing from viewport, when WGTS_rig collection set to Enable In Viewports, the armature shows but isn't posable

Tags: animation, armature

The armature doesn't show on the character, I've tried to unhide using `alt+h` to no av

[image: The armature doesn't show on the character, I've tried to unhide it but it didn't work]

[image: The armature is greyed out in the outliner for some reason]The armature is greyed out in the outliner

[image: Enable in Viewports on the collection shows the armature, but no options for pose mode and moving the pieces don't affect the character, I cannot animate the character like this] `Enable in Viewports` on the collection shows the armature, but no options for pose mode and moving the pieces don't affect the character, I cannot animate the character like this

[image: The character is still affected by the animation I made before] The character is still affected by the animation I made before

Comment: If you've used Rigify to generate the rig and correctly parented your object you're supposed to use the rig widgets to pose it not the armature bones. Also make sure you're using the correct widget on the arms and legs for the appropriate FK-IK setting on the N panel.

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped me think about it differently, I found an object icon of what looked to be a stickman in the outliner, then I went to edit model to reveal the rig  and from then I was able to enter pose mode and alt+h helped to reveal the widgets for the rig to solve the problem I had.